# Effective Rate of Interest and Inflation Problem

Tags: actuarial-science

I'm trying to solve the following question from a past SOA FM exam, but there are no posted solutions so I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction.

> John deposits 10, 000 in a saving account which he assumes is paying 7% per annum interest effective. He has calculated that after 7 years he will be able to buy the hang glider he wants if its price inflates at a rate of 3% per annum effective. In fact the hang glider’s price inflates at only 1% per annum and the interest rate on the account is dropped to 5% per annum immediately after he makes the deposit. How many years does he have to wait for the hang glider?

P = Price of the hang glider

Under the old conditions of 7% per annum interest and inflation of 3% per annum effective:

> $10,000 (1.07)^7 = P (1.03)^7$
>
> $P = 13,056.47$

Under the new conditions of 5% per annum interest and inflation of 1% per annum effective, it'll take n years for John to save for the hand glider:

> $10,000 (1.05)^n = 13,056.47 (1.01)^n$
>
> $\left(\frac{1.05}{1.01}\right)^n = \left(\frac{13,056.47}{10,0000}\right)$
>
> $n \times \ln\left(\frac{1.05}{1.01}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{13,056.47}{10,0000}\right)$
>
> $n = 6.87$

So I get that it'll take over 6 years (which is one of the MPC answers). Any feedback? Thank you.

Comment: Please use [$MathJax$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) while posting anything here.

Comment: I think your reasoning looks correct.

Comment: If the inflation is $3\%$, then the factor is $100\%-3\%=97\%=0.97$. Therefore the future value in the first case is $10.000 \cdot (1.07\cdot 0.97)^7$. Beside this I would round up your result. So the answer is 7 years.

Comment: I've checked your answer and it's well done. The correct answer is more than 6 years.

Comment: @callculus inflation means increase in price! so you have $+3\%$. You'll have the minus sign in case of deflation (decrease of prices).

Answer (score 0):

The answer as described by the OP is correct.

[Closing, but making community wiki so as not to take credit for another's answer.]